# mouse_pos event for button kivy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to change the background color of a button when the mouse hovers, and to create the callback, I tried the following code snippet

```
    self.btn.bind(mouse_pos = self.on_mouse_hover)
```

but am faced with the **KeyError** for **mouse_pos**

```
    KeyError: 'mouse_pos'
```

Is mouse_pos defined only for **Window** and not for widgets in kivy? Or am I missing any import statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `mouse_pos` is defined only for Window. You can instead bind to the Window event for it, and in the bound function iterate over your widgets.

Comment: Thank you for the suggest. If it is not too much to ask, can you please provide a small code snippet to state an example? I am new to kivy. @inclement